# Creating multi-row toolbar in ArcGIS Engine?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, arcgis-engine

I am using ArcGIS Engine 10.1 and Visual Studio 2010

I created a MapControl App,
(New Project>Visual C#> ArcGIS>Extending ArcObjects > MapControl Application)

and added a toolbar
(In MainForm and right-click on ToolbarControl > Properties  > Open Items Tab > Add > Add some commands to toolbar).

The Problem is items won't fit in a single toolbar and I can't manage to create a multi-row toolbar. In addition Items wont scroll at run time.

So is there any solution to make an ArcGIS Engine multi-row toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

You are right: You need a second ToolbarControl. It cannot be multirow by itself. If you can't add another one in the UI-Designer you need to do it in code. I'm not familiar with WinForms, but there should be a way to change the view from Designer to code for the MainForm.